# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I have users and projects table. in project table user_id is foreign key. i create a project and when i try to save the project details its showing this ERROR:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`labtest`.`projects`, CONSTRAINT `projects_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `Projects` (`name`, `description`, `date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (e, e, 2017-12-31, 2017-09-19 15:21:06, 2017-09-19 15:21:06))

how i can solve this?

users table migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

projects table migration

```
   Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->timestamps('date');
    });



   Schema::table('projects',function(Blueprint $table)
    {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

user model:

```
 public function project()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
  }
```

project model:

```
  public function user() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','user_id');
   }
```

controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
    ]);


    Project::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('projects.index')
                    ->with('success','Project created successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two alternatives :

- **First one :**

  ```
  $data = $request->all();
  $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
  Project::create($data);
  //....
  ```
- **Second one :**

  ```
  Auth::user()->project()->create($request->all());
  ```

Comment: yes.its working.now i can save the data in database.thank you but why this error is showing when i try to view the the user_id and project details  . ERROR:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Projects` where exists (select * from `users` where `Projects`.`id` = `users`.`user_id`))

Comment: here is the index controller function                                                   
    $projects = Project::whereHas('user')->get();
    return view('projects.index', compact('projects','users'));

Comment: because there is a problem in the relationship of the model, change it to : `public function user() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }`

Comment: in the doc you have `return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');` you can leave it like i did in the previous comment or like this `public function user() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id', 'id');
   }` ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you defined the projects table, `user_id` is not nullable. So if you want to insert a project, you have to pass a valid `user_id` to the `create()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user then use that to create the project like so:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$user->project()->create([
     $request->all()
]);
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to put the 'user_id' directly as $fillable. Of course you would want to add those (other) fields to fillable in the model (since you are using `create()` method)

One thing observed is the pluralization of your related model, I think you can avoid confusion by using `projects` rather than `project` since its one user to many projects.